# How can I get the price of NFT on Opensea using chainlink?

Tags: solidity, nft, polygon, chainlink, opensea

I have tried to use the chainlink and contract address of NFT to fetch the price but I am not sure where I am wrong

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;


constructor() {
    priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x495f947276749Ce646f68AC8c248420045cb7b5e);
}

/**
 * Returns the latest price
 */
function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
    (
        /*uint80 roundID*/,
        int price,
        /*uint startedAt*/,
        /*uint timeStamp*/,
        /*uint80 answeredInRound*/
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return price;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you are attempting to return the price of an NFT using price feeds.

`priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x495f947276749Ce646f68AC8c248420045cb7b5e);` This interface needs to use the address of an interface contract for pricefeeds.
Example: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419#code

A further list and explanation can be found in the [Chainlink Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/reference-contracts/).

It might be possible to return prices based on [OpenSea's API](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/api-overview) using [Any API](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data/).