# How to we fetch price of NFT index using chainlink

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nft, oracles, chainlink

i was wondering if we can fetch the price of different NFT index using chainlink price oracle, i had done the same earlier to find the pricefeed for ETH to USD , now i want same for NFT collection.

Comment: Please see answer in this question
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/130855/how-can-i-get-the-price-of-nft-on-opensea-using-chainlink

Comment: There is no answer there

Answer (score -1):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract NFTFloorPriceConsumerV3 {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal nftFloorPriceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Goerli - No Sepolia feeds available at this time
     * Aggregator: CryptoPunks
     * Address: 0x5c13b249846540F81c093Bc342b5d963a7518145
     */
    constructor() {
        nftFloorPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0x5c13b249846540F81c093Bc342b5d963a7518145
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        // prettier-ignore
        (
            /*uint80 roundID*/,
            int nftFloorPrice,
            /*uint startedAt*/,
            /*uint timeStamp*/,
            /*uint80 answeredInRound*/
        ) = nftFloorPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return nftFloorPrice;
    }
}
```